# SQL*Plus connection SetUp: ORA-12154 Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Sorry for the noob question but I am new to Oracle SQL software.

I've been trying to create a connection to my database **student** (created on SQL Developer), but got quite confusing since I'm using a client-computer which will connect to server.

Below are the info about the connection:

**Connection Name**: LARGER123

**Username**: LARGER123

**Hostname**: uxkg265.admin.plent

**Port**: 1520

**SID**: ticp5076

**Client-computer username**: r5678

[image]

When I open the SQL Plus prompt, I tried several combinations on the username in order to establish the connection, but got the same error **ORA-12154 Error**.

I though that it could be the way I was setting the things on username field, so I followed the instructions from Oracle's website:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-1A15D322-B3AC-426A-86A1-EB7590930687.htm#ADMQS045

Basically it tells to "build" the username structure in that way:

```
   nick@"dbhost.example.com/orcl.example.com"
```

Where: **"nick"** is the user; **"dbhost.example.com"** is the host; and **"orcl.example.com"** is the database.

So, following the example I put my username in that way and got errors:

```
   LARGER123@"uxkg265.admin.plent/student"
```

I tried different ways, including the **Port** and **SID** but got no success.

Do you have a better idea of what's my mistake?

Comment: Are these publicly available networks? You might want to scrub your network/usernames

Answer (score 0):

Are you quite certain somebody is listening where you are trying to connect.  I would suggest you start by testing with telnet.

You say your server has the domain name “uxkg265.admin.plent”

```
nslookup uxkg265.admin.plent
```

I just checked my IP address and found:

```
$ nslookup $(hostname)
Server:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:        xxx.xxx.xxx.xx##53
Name:   mydomain.myorg.com
Address: 192.168.56.1
```

I just tried to connect to my oracle instance and got:

```
$ telnet  192.168.56.1 1521
Trying 192.168.56.1...
Connected to 192.168.56.1
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

If I try to the wrong port, I get:

```
$ telnet  192.168.56.1 1522
Trying 192.168.56.1...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.56.1: Connection refused
```

I was able to connect with:

```
sqlplus myoracle/testpass@192.168.56.1:1521/UPGR
```

where UPGR is the service name.

I was also able to connect with:

```
sqlplus myoracle/testpass@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.56.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=UPGR)))"
```

With UPGR as the SID.

I had some trouble initially because my version of Oracle Linux had iptables enabled and that was keeping me from connecting using sqlplus.  As soon as I disabled this protection, I was able to use Oracle.

```
sudo service iptables stop
sudo chkconfig iptables off
```

(Keep in mind that iptables serves a purpose.  For my test system running on my PC in VirtualBox, turning it off is fine.  For other systems, maybe not.)

Comment: I tried the telnet but the prompt got cleared and nothing appeared though the window's title indicated **telnet 10.89.133.98**. To quit or turn back to prompt I just typed enter.

Comment: Always get:

`ERROR:`

`ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: Since you have the IP address, it would be interesting to try that with sqlplus: `sqlplus LARGER123/@"(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=TCP)(host=10.89.133.98)(port=1521)))(service_name=(SID=ticp5076)))"`.  This has something to do with "TNS..resolve". Interesting.

Comment: When you try sqlplus ... how long does it take before you get the error?  Is it right away or more than 30 seconds?

Comment: Do you have access to the command prompt on your server machine?  I wonder if you would get the same `TNS:could not resolve` error there, as well.

Comment: Here is something else to try: create a file called `tnsnames.ora` in your local directory and `set TNS_ADMIN=.` (on windows) `export TNS_ADMIN=.` (on Unix/Linux) and run `sqlplus LARGER123/@ORCL` where ORCL is the name from your `tnsnames.ora` file.  As an experiment I assigned my `TNS_ADMIN` variable somewhere I don't have a `tnsnames.ora` file and I got your error.  If I set it correctly, the error went away.

Comment: I got the following error after setting the `TNS_ADMIN`: 
`SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]`.

Comment: Generally the error takes about 5 seconds to be generated on the first time. After that it is almost instantly.

Comment: I don't have access to the server machine unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12154 is `TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`, but you likely aren't using TNS to resolve the connect identifier: have you edited the `tnsnames.ora` file on the client machine and created an entry for the SID you're trying to connect to?  Probably not.

Instead of selecting SID, select "Service name" and put the Oracle SID there.  With the "Basic" connection type, that should use the host/port and service name explicitly to build the connection rather than relying on TNS to look up (resolve) the SID.

Comment: basic connections won't look at tnsnames at all on the client - but need to use service over sid for 12c and higher connections if multitenant

Comment: I put the following:
ORCL =
 (description=
   (address_list=
     (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = uxkg265.admin.plent)(port = 1521))
   )
 (service_name =
   (SID=ticp5076)
 )
)

Comment: And tried with "Service Name = " instead of "service_name", but got no success. Sorry for my noob doubts....

Comment: Could this be a matter of port number confusion?  In your original post you claim port number is 1520, in your screenshot you used 1520, but the default port for the SQL*Net Listener is 1521 - could your problem be as simple as a typo of the port number?

Comment: Try: `ORCL = (description= (address= (protocol= tcp) (host= uxkg265.admin.plent) (port= 1521)) (connect_data= (service_name= ticp5076)))` - but double-check what the correct port number is.